How to Access UNC Path Over VPN from Windows Docker Container
My application need to reach a UNC path (like \\server_name\folder_name) from docker container.
The UNC is reachable within a VPN. My app can reach it from my computer while run directly but fails to reach it while running from docker container (all the time I am connected to the VPN). I am using windows docker container.
I have tried configuring it while using docker network create -d transparent my-transparent-network and run it using docker run --network my-transparent-network --rm use_network_image, but still have no network / ip address / access from container to the server. How to configure the docker to reach such UNC resource?

Can you verify that the server itself is reachable from within the Docker container?

It is not reachable within the Docker container, that is the problem, I can't reach no network from within the docker container
